# UIscrollview scrolls other scrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an 3 `uiscrollviews` like myscroll1, myscroll2, myscroll3..etc..,which i have added as subviews in my view class, **each one positioned one below one**. Like,
[image]Here i need to  scroll all the scroll views parllely, i.e if i touch and scroll any `scrollview` all the `scrollview` has to be scrolled. is it possible.?

Comment: Why would you want 3 seperate scrollViews when they move the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up delegates for your scroll views and implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` to update the content offset of the other scroll views.

Comment: That's not existing code; it's the delegate method that you need to write to manipulate your scroll views.

Comment: i have done myscroll.delegate=self; myscroll1.delegate=self, myscroll2.delegate=self;